# printing a grid. Mine is incorrect

Tags: c

I'm trying to print a grid of 10 points (x, y). I read the points from a file.

The points I am reading in:

```
7 19
11 5
15 11
4 10
1 8
10 4
2 5
14 12
10 9
12 4
```

The grid is 20x20 (0 <= x <= 19) and I also want to find the closest points to each other marked by a different char which will be "X".

I wrote the points and grid into a file so the cmd input looks like this: <a.out> <points.txt> <output.txt>

The 1st screenshot is how the output should look but I get a completely different grid output which is shown in the second sc. Need help as to why this is?

[image: correct grid output. How it should look like]

[image: incorrect grid output]

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 10  // Do NOT change this line!

typedef struct gPoints
 {
     int x;
     int y;
 }point2d;

void fill(char filename[], point2d P[]);
int getdist(point2d p, point2d q);
void closest(point2d P[], int G[2*N][2*N]);
void grid(point2d P[], int G[2*N][2*N]);
void printpoints(char filename[], point2d P[]);
void printgridxy(char filename[], int G[2*N][2*N]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Syntax Error: ./a.out <infile> <outfile>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    point2d P[N];
    int G[2*N][2*N] = {0};

    fill(argv[1], P);
    grid(P, G);
    printpoints(argv[2], P);
    printgridxy(argv[2], G);


    return 0;
}

void fill(char filename[], point2d P[])
{
    /**
     * This function opens and reads from the input file.  You should close the 
     * file when you are done with it.  Read the points into the array of 
     * structures in this function.
     *
     * Don't forget to check if the file name is valid.
     */

    // open and read
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    // error check
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("Cannot open file!\n");
     
          int i = 0;
          while(!feof(fp))
           {
               int x, y;
               fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &x, &y);
               P[i].x = x;
               P[i].y = y;
               i++;
           }
    // close file
     fclose(fp); 
}

int getdist(point2d p, point2d q)
{
    /**
     * This function gets the distance between 2 points and returns that value.
     * 
     * Yes, you need to do some math here...
     * 
     * You should return the squared distance, rather than taking the square root.
     */
    int closest_dist = (q.x-p.x)*(q.x-p.x) + (p.y-q.y)*(p.y-q.y); 
    return closest_dist;
    
}
// pass in struct var as an arg: point2d P[] - an array of n points P[]
void closest(point2d P[], int G[2*N][2*N]) // 20x20
{
    /**
     * This function finds the 2 points that are the closest.
     * 
     * You should call the getdist() function from inside here.
     */

    // find the 2 points that are closest
    // first find the min distance between (7,19) (11,5). this will be the distance compared against dist
    int cmpDist = getdist(P[0],P[1]);  
    point2d point1 = P[0], point2 = P[1];
    int i,j;
    i = j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for(j = i+1; j < N; ++j){
            int dist = getdist(P[i], P[j]); 
            if(dist <= cmpDist){ // if dist less than minDist, set dist as the new minDist
               point1 = P[i];
               point2 = P[j];
               cmpDist = dist;
           }
      }
 }

// set values in G to unique values
G[point1.x][point1.y] = 26;
G[point2.x][point2.y] = 26; // fav number i guess
}

void grid(point2d P[], int G[2*N][2*N]){
    /**
     * This function will transfer all the points from your structure into a 
     * 2D array used as the grid.
     * 
     * You will call the closest() function from inside here.
     */

    int i, j;
    i = j = 0;
    // set G for each of the N points
    for(i = 0; i < 2*N; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < 2*N; ++j)
            G[i][j] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        G[P[i].x][P[i].y] = 1;
    }
    closest(P, G);
}

void printpoints(char filename[], point2d P[]){

    /**
     * This function will print off the list of all the points you have in the 
     * following form:
     * 
     * num: (x, y)
     * 
     * ex.
     * 0: ( 4,  1)
     * 1: (12, 13)
     * 
     * **Note the spacing!**
     * 
     * You need to open the output file here and write to it.
     */

    // open the output file amd write to it
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    // print off the list of all the points in the following form: num: (x, y). 
    fprintf(fp, "0: ( %d, %d)\n", P[0].x, P[0].y);
    fprintf(fp, "1: (%d,  %d)\n", P[1].x, P[1].y);
    fprintf(fp, "2: (%d, %d)\n", P[2].x, P[2].y);
    fprintf(fp, "3: ( %d, %d)\n", P[3].x, P[3].y);
    fprintf(fp, "4: ( %d,  %d)\n", P[4].x, P[4].y);
    fprintf(fp, "5: (%d,  %d)\n", P[5].x, P[5].y);
    fprintf(fp, "6: ( %d,  %d)\n", P[6].x, P[6].y);
    fprintf(fp, "7: (%d, %d)\n", P[7].x, P[7].y);
    fprintf(fp, "8: (%d,  %d)\n", P[8].x, P[8].y);
    fprintf(fp, "9: (%d,  %d)\n", P[9].x, P[9].y);
}

void printgridxy(char filename[], int G[2*N][2*N]){

    /**
     * This function will print out your 2D array (the grid)
     * 
     * Use ' ' for spots without a point,
     * use '*' for spots with a point,
     * use 'X' for the 2 points that are closest.
     * 
     * Put 1 space between each element, for example you should print "* "
     * instead of just "*".
     * 
     * 
     * You should also have a top and bottom made of 50 hyphens (-)
     * 
     * This should be printed to the same file as the points were.
     * Be careful not to overwrite the file!
     */

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "a"); // file is opened only for appending
    int i, j;
    i = j = 0;
    // top made of 50 hyphens
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "-");
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2*N; i++)
    {
         for(j = 0; j < 2*N; j++)
             if(G[i][j] == 0)
                 fprintf(fp, "  "); // 1 space between each element
             else if(G[i][j] == 26)
                 fprintf(fp, "X "); // 1 space between each element
             else
                 fprintf(fp, "* "); // 1 space between each element
         fprintf(fp, "\n");                
     }
    // bottom made of 50 hyphens 
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "-");
}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of a kazillion `fprintf` calls, consider making a scratch string buffer that's cleaned out with spaces, then populated as necessary. There's no need to compute this stuff "on the fly" here. If you do it right, you can dump the whole buffer out in one call.

Comment: The first screenshot is **incorrect**. Look at the row numbers for elements to set to be an asterisk... It looks like row 1 might be correct - (1,8) showing a point at 1,16... Where are the 'stars' for rows 2 and 4?? That screenshot is wrong... Your code is verbose, but it looks alright to me... Hasn't this been fun???